# How to get Pencil-Sketch Effect?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, drawing

I am trying to get this kind of Pencil-Sketch Effect in Photoshop, but without much luck:

[image: Programmers logo that exhibits this effect]

Being new to Photoshop, I need either exact steps to bring this effect or links to tutorials.

Anyone have an idea about how this can be done?

Answer (score 2):

These links should help,mainly the last one
Photoshop [help](http://photoshop-help.com/)
Web Design Library:[Pencil Shading Effect](http://www.webdesign.org/photoshop/photo-editing/pencil-shading-effect.14757.html)
Psdguides: [Photoshop Tutorials](http://psdguides.com/2009/09/pencil-sketching/)
they also have Photoshop forums you may want to join if new to it- good luck

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the procedure given by mic84, there is also this one:

[Photo to Pencil Sketch](http://www.graphic-design.com/Photoshop/pencil_sketch/index.html)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There is no easy way to create this in PS. The only option is to select the text (Ctrl+click on the text layer) and try sketching inside the selection with a really thin brush. Of course that is not that easy and usually - really time consuming.

You can try using Adobe Illustrator - it takes only five mins to create such Scribble effect. Here is a really good and easy to follow tutorial - http://vectips.com/tutorials/turn-any-font-into-a-sketch-font/ Just set the Fill and Stroke to the color you need. That is probably how the text effect in the picture posted in the question was created.

Another option would be to use a font like Sketch Block (or anything else you can find online) - http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/artill-typs/sketch-block/

Answer (score 1):

You can try this tutorial for creating sketch text in Photoshop
http://www.psd-dude.com/tutorials/photoshop.aspx?t=create-a-sketch-text-in-photoshop

Or you can buy one of these cool Photoshop Sketch Actions
http://www.psd-dude.com/tutorials/resources/sketch-photoshop-premium-styles-and-actions.aspx